# How to represent a single space character in a square bracket group

Tags: regex

I'm facing an issue to represent a single space in the [] character set expression. I ended up using something like this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]|\x20)+
```

which i think is not very elegant

**Update**: I now know what is going wrong with my regex. I used something like this which did not work

```
[A-Za-z0-9/.,':!?$%()- ]+
```

But when I move the space to be after 9 like this

```
[A-Za-z0-9 /.,':!?$%()-]+
```

And it works, just weird. I'm trying this with an online regex tester [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/).

**Update2**: I figured out now the issue is that `-` inside regex is used to represent a range in `[]` so anything before and after it has different meaning than just being a plain character

Comment: Either `[ ]` or `[\s]` for a space.

Comment: Please add an example input string, and what you'd expect to match. Also an input string that doesn't match

Comment: If you plan to use `/x` modifier (may be in future) then you way is better.

Comment: @AD7six, no need to add example here, it's an issue caused by me being not familiar with regex

Comment: as a general rule, if you need to use `-` in a character class, put it _first_.

Comment: @Eevee or last. simply not in the middle where it means a range is fine

Comment: @AD7six putting it first means you won't accidentally turn it into a range when you add more characters later  :)

Comment: @Eevee good point - I think it's important to clarify which things are  a reason and which are a convention - hence clarifying you _can_ put it as the last char.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

will add a space to the character class. I'm guessing you already know that and you want to make sure that there will be only *single* spaces in your string. In that case, you need an additional lookahead:

```
^(?!.*  )[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$
```

matches a string that contains alphanumerics and spaces, but only single spaces.

Comment: Can also use `^(\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\s?$` to get the single whitespace without the lookahead

Comment: @blgt: That regex is prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Try it on the string `"abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc!"`, that'll keep your computer busy for quite a while...

Comment: ^ Generally you are right: nesting expansions is bad, however the ^$ make it more acceptable. As long as you don't run massive strings with no spaces through it it should be fine. The example you gave executes instantaneously (?), at least when I run it through the firefox console.

Comment: @blgt: Firefox aborts a regex match attempt if it takes too long. Other browsers like Chrome won't - they'll freeze up for minutes. Same for most programming languages used for server-side regex validation. The anchors alleviate the problem a bit, but not enough. Also, the number of spaces is irrelevant, `"abcabcabc abcabcab cabcabca bcabc!"` fails just the same way.

Comment: Good to know! Tried running it through a couple different places. Powershell froze up for about 15 seconds, and the 1.7 jdk under Redhat for about 5. The couple of other matchers didn't, they probably do something similar to Firefox.

Answer (score 11):

You can *just* use a space.

For the regex structure in the question:

```
 ([a-zA-Z0-9]| )+
```

In practice:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
```